# Once + present perfect + present simple

Tags: meaning, tense, sentence-structure

I wrote 2 sentences:

Many ethnic groups migrated into Vietnamese territory at different historical periods: some came thousands of years ago and some came hundreds of years ago. Regardless of that, **once you have lived on the S-shaped strip of land***, you are all considered of the same roots and are compatriots united by mutual understanding, allegiance, attachment and care.

*Vietnam is a long, narrow nation shaped like the letter S.

The problem is in bold:

Once you have lived on the S-shaped strip of land--> Does it make sense? I want to imply that those ethnic groups resided and still to this day reside in Vietnam. However, after it I use Present Simple (you are all considered...) which I think is not very suitable since I usually see Future tense after Once + Present perfect such as: Once I've done my homework, I'll go out

Comment: Well-written question , +1 ! I think you are trying to make a comparison with this "once you have lived ... , you /will be/ considered". If so , that will make more sense to those who are yet to live there (eg new immigrants wanting to be citizens) & not suitable to current citizens who have lived there for generations. If you are talking to "foreigners who have recently become citizens" & you want to say they are equal citizens , you can say "you will be". Talking about existing citizens , you can say "having lived [here] , you are all considered compatriots". Nothing wrong with your wording.

Comment: It is not a strip of land. A strip of land would be much smaller than Vietnam....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about ethnic groups that have lived in Vietnam for a long time, then "once" is the wrong conjunction.

"Once" can mean "as soon as", or it can mean "if...ever", but neither of these meanings apply:

> "As soon as you have lived in Vietnam, you are considered of the same roots."
> "If you have ever lived in Vietnam, you are considered of the same roots."

Clearly, neither of these is the meaning you're after.

Consider something like, "***Any people who have settled on** the S-shaped piece of land...*". Here I use "people" in the sense of "ethnic group", not the plural of "person".